# How to share objects in different test in PHPUnit

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I have the following class 'MyControllerTest' for testing purposes of 'MyController'.
I want to share the same object which is '$algorithms' in different tests of this classes but I don't know how to do that after trying adding the variable in different places:

```
class MyControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    // $algorithms = ...   <----- does not work
    public static function main()
    {
        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite("MyControllerTest");
        $result = PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::run($suite);
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(
                'testing',
                APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
        );
        $configuration = Zend_Registry::get('configuration');
        // $algorithms = ...   <----- does not work
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {

    }
    public function test1() {
        // this array shared in different tests
        $algorithms[0] = array(            

                        "class" => "Mobile",
                        "singleton" => "true",
                        "params" => array(
                                "mobile" => "true",
                                "phone" => "false"
                                )
                    );

        ...  
    } 
    public function test2() { };

}
```

How can I share this object? 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Define it in your setUp(), then it's available to all tests in the class (though yoru existing definition of $algorithms is an array, not an object).... but remember that `$algorithms` !== `$this->algorithms`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a couple of options here

1. Declare the data fixture right into the setUp method and declare a private variable that holds it. So you can use it in the other test methods.
2. Declare a private function within your test class that holds your data fixture. If you need the data fixture just call the private method
3. Create a Utiltity class with a method that holds the data fixture. The Utility class is   initialized in the setUp function. Declare a private variable within the MyControllerTest that holds the instance of the Utility class. When a test needs the fixture just call the fixture method from the Utility instance.

Example 1

```
class MyControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase 
{
  private $alg;

  public function setUp()
  {
    # variable that holds the data fixture
    $this->alg = array(....);
  }

  public function test1()
  {
     $this->assertCount(1, $this->alg);
  }
}
```

Example 2

```
class MyControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase 
{
  public function test1()
  {
     $this->assertCount(1, $this->getAlgo());
  }

  # Function that holds the data fixture
  private function getAlgo()
  {
    return array(....);
  }
}
```

Example 3

```
class Utility
{
  # Function that holds the data fixture
  public function getAlgo()
  {
    return array(....);
  }
}

class MyControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase 
{
  private $utility;

  public function setUp()
  {
    $this->utility = new Utility();
  }

  public function test1()
  {
     $this->assertCount(1, $this->utility->getAlgo());
  }
}
```

But beware of fixtures that are shared and are altered in some tests. This can really mess up your test suite.

Comment: Thanks for this! This was my first PHPUnitTest class and I was little confused. I prefer the first option! :-D